# Retrograde Go Problem (Some Assembly Required)

Tags: board-games, construction, retrograde-analysis

<sub>An entry into the [Fortnightly Topic Challenge #40.](https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6490/fortnightly-topic-challenge-40-retrograde-analysis)</sub>

---

> In case you aren't familiar with the rules of go, the information in the [basic rules section](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Go_(game)#Basic_rules) of the Wikipedia page should be enough to solve this puzzle. Anyway, here we *go*:
>
> Given the following position, and this knowledge:
>
> 1. The game started on an [empty 6x6 board](https://tromp.github.io/go/learn/wow0.gif)
> 2. Exactly 5 moves have been played
> 3. There have been no passes
>
> What was the last move black played?
>
> Here's the position:

---

(Sorry, gotta run. Surely you can construct a suitable position for this problem yourself? Remember to make it solvable though!)

---

*If it should so happen that there were more than one such position, the one where the stones fit inside the smallest rectangle is the winner.*

Comment: cannot see any photo

Comment: @oray that’s the joke.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm reasonably sure this is the best possible solution.

> [image: Go Board]

The most recent move must be

> Black playing the corner, having captured White in the corner on their previous move.

Answer (score 5):

I believe (without proof) that the only solution up to symmetry is:

> [image]
> *(Yay for smartphone drawing skills!)*

This is solvable since:

> White must have played two stones, so one is captured: that must be on the square between the three blacks. But there couldn’t have been a black in the corner when the second white stone was played (it would have been taken) so the black stone in the corner must have been the last played.

Comment: Very good! There is another, somewhat simpler solution though.

Comment: I only just remembered that on this site multiple solutions are frowned upon, so I added a tie breaker to the question. Your solution has the tie breaker score 6  (2 times 3 intersections), which is pretty good.